# PHP Redirects work in every browser but Edge

Tags: php, redirect, microsoft-edge

This PHP redirect works with every browser but Edge:

```
http://localhost/index.php/de/tag-suche?agdetagsearchs_checkbox[0]=2&Agdetagsearch=1&language=de-DE&Itemid=111&option=com_agdetagsearchs&lang=de-DE&view=category&id=11&limit=20&agtagscolumnlimit=3&agtagscolumnlimit_fields=1&agde_language=all#agdetagsearch-resultlist
```

The problem does not exist in any other browsers. 
When I manually type the URL into the address bar, it also renders properly.
I tried to use Post instead of GET, but the form did not submit as well.
I tried it with different web servers and different clients.

I found this question: [Microsoft Edge does not redirect page with Chinese characters properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327689/microsoft-edge-does-not-redirect-page-with-chinese-characters-properly)
This could be a similar problem. Also I do not use Chinese characters.

Comment: Try using `urlencode()` to properly encode special characters in the query string. `[0]` should be encoded as `%5B0%5D`. You can use `http_build_query()` to format the entire query string

Comment: Concert the string to Utf-8 & use urlencode before redirecting